# массовый перенос файлов указанных в списке(текстовом документе)

Tags: shell

есть текстовый документ в котором лежит список файлов:
file1.zip
file2.zip
и тд

и есть папка в которой лежит много файлов

Подскажите как из этой папки перенести файлы которые указанны в текстовом документе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

перемещаются файлы/каталоги, как обычно, программой *mv*. синтаксис вызова (см. `$ man mv`):

```
$ mv источник1 ... назначение
```

подставить список источников из файла можно, например, с помощью оператора [подстановки команд `$(...)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03):

```
$ mv $(cat файл-со-списком) назначение
```

если пути к файлам указаны относительно какого-то каталога, то, естественно, перед выполнением команды надо сделать этот каталог текущим с помощью встроенной команды `cd`.